# Issues with NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I'm trying to load multiple images from the web asynchronously. Looking I found this forum post "[Loading/Downloading image from URL on Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-image-from-url)" but I still have some "issues".

I have this code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let newCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("userCell") as! UserCell_TableViewCell
let selectedUser = userArray[indexPath.row]

newCell.userDescription?.text = selectedUser.getFirstName() + " " + selectedUser.getLastName()

if let userImage = selectedUser.getImage()
{
    // NO CODE
}
else
{
    newCell.userImage.downloadedFrom(self.imageArray[arrayIndex])
}

return newCell
```

}

```
extension UIImageView {

    func downloadedFrom(urlLink :String)
    {
        if let urlData = NSURL(string: urlLink) {

            NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(urlData, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

                if error == nil
                {

                    print("Correct URL: " + "\(urlLink)")
                }
                else
                {
                    print("Incorrect URL: " + "\(urlLink)")
                }

            }).resume()
        }
    }
}
```

PROBLEM

1) to test, I enter right and wrong directions, but always tells me to be correct.
[image]

QUESTIONS

1) It is possible that the image can return it for use elsewhere?

2) How do to detect that the URL is invalid and thus enter a default image?

**EDIT**

Optional( { URL: http://findicons.com/files/icons/1072/face_avatars/300/a03.png } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 32759;
    "Content-Type" = "image/png";
    Date = "Fri, 23 Oct 2015 14:20:20 GMT";
    "Last-Modified" = "Thu, 11 Feb 2010 10:49:27 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.1.19";
} })

Optional( { URL: http://findicons.com/files/icons/1072/face_avatars/300/a01_BLABLABLA.png } { status code: 404, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Language" = en;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Fri, 23 Oct 2015 18:01:11 GMT";
    Server = "gunicorn/0.17.4";
    "Set-Cookie" = "csrftoken=81phPal08h22q6d87lC85TqCCOniJhhJ; expires=Fri, 21-Oct-2016 18:01:11 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding, Cookie, Accept-Language";
} })

Comment: Try logging the `response`.

Comment: @matt thx! go to edit

Comment: There you go. You get a 404, there is no such object, your data is empty. What's the problem?

Comment: @matt What I need it is if the image exists, put that on my cell UIImageView, if not, leave the default one

Comment: Sounds good. You do that. I believe I've answered the question.

Comment: @matt "There you go. You get a 404, there is no such object, your data is empty. What's the problem?" always returns data, whether the address is correct or incorrect

Comment: And that data is empty and is not an image. _What's the problem?_ I've answered the question you asked: I've explained _completely_ what you asked about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `response` is an NSHTTPURLResponse. If its `statusCode` is `404` you have no data and should go no further.

The reason you're not getting an error is that there was no error; this is a perfectly valid and complete communication back and forth across the network.

Comment: Ahhhhh That is the reason, you can capture when the image address is not valid?

Comment: @If I disconnect the PC Internet, I get what I need O.o                                  

Correct URL: http://findicons.com/files/icons/1072/face_avatars/300/a02.png
Correct URL: http://findicons.com/files/icons/1072/face_avatars/300/a04.png
Correct URL: http://findicons.com/files/icons/1072/face_avatars/300/a03.png
Correct URL: http://findicons.com/files/icons/1072/face_avatars/300/a02.png
Incorrect URL: http://findicons.com/files/icons/1072/face_avatars/300/a01_BLABLABLA.png
Incorrect URL: http://findicons.com/files/icons/1072/face_avatars/300/a01_BLABLABLA.png